# How to transfer photos from my Macbook Air to an android smartphone?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, android

Not sure if this question has been asked before, so apologies if it has:

I have some photos on my MacBook Air, which I want to transfer onto my Android smartphone, which is a Lenovo.

I'm not sure how to do that and have not been able to find much info online.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A really quick Google search turns up [two methods](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/08/transfer-photos-from-android-to-mac-os-x/) for doing this

1. Plug the Android phone into your Mac and use the Image Capture.app
2. Use the Android file transfer app